# Rails não aceita requisição

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Montei uma API simples no Rails, ela somente lê o banco de dados, e retorna o JSON de acordo com a requisição.

Entretanto, fui testar a API, fazendo uma requisição com um outro dispositivo, conectado via wireless, e não consegui obter o JSON como resposta. Procurei o erro na internet, e parece que é algo relacionado ao `protect_from_forgery`, mas mesmo eu comentando ele, não consegui. 
Assim, a API não tem muita coisa relacionada a segurança, por exemplo, requerir token e coisas afins, pois sou iniciante, e não sei muito bem como desenvolver essa parte.

Segue o link do github para o projeto: https://github.com/ViniciusVenancio/fatec-api

Answer (score 0):

Sem detalhes do que e como vc está acessando, fica meio no chute, mas

provavelmente você está tendo problema de [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Essa gem resolve:

https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors

Comment: Assim, eu faço uma requisição em outra máquina, a minha API, localhost, e eu não consigo. Fala que a conexão rejeitada ou deu tempo limite excedido.

Comment: E também parece que seria algo relacionado ao token, pois a requisição não envia tokens

Comment: Mas a sua aplicação funciona no localhost sem token?

Comment: Sim, normal. É que assim, eu crio uma arquivo ruby, que eu faço a requisição, por que na verdade, eu vou utilizar essa API, para retornar dados para dispositivos móveis, aí eu não obtenho respostas

Answer (score 0):

Faça o seguinte

Editar conforme abaixo /controllers/applications
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session